# Tabbable Navs Using Javascript In Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a tabbable nav for three forms on my web page. I can't get the Javascript to work for the tabs. There are two scripts on the Twitter Documentation.

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

and

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show'); // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

This is the html for the tabbable navs given on the documentation.

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I use these two code blocks on my webpage to show appropriate content when one of the two tabs is clicked? I am a Javascript Newbie. Just want to get things done.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to enable the tabs individually because of the data-toggle='tab' attribute on each tab. Make sure you've added the [bootstrap.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js) file to your page.

If you want, you can take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/voytko/TVUPF/